# How to exclude users with no posts from a user list?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to reshape my "users" page [here](http://wordsinthebucket.com/contributors) for a Wordpress website.

I would like to exclude from the list those contributors which do not have written any post.

In this case the list is by role->contributor; I'm aware that I could just change the role of those users with 0 posts to "subscriber" or similar. But I would like to have a more fluid solution.

Thank you for your help.

```html
 <?php

/*
Template Name: Display Contributors and Authors
*/

    $args = array(
         'role'    => 'contributor',
         'orderby' => 'post_count',
         'order'   => 'DESC'
    );
    $contributors = get_users( $args );

    ?>

<?php get_header();?>
<div id="main">
<div id="primary" class="three-parts archive">
<div class="widget-title">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
    <div id="blog-list" class="blog-category">
    <ul>    
        <?php

        foreach($contributors as $contributor) 

     {

        ?>
        <li style="margin-top: 10px; width:25%;">   
            <div class="blog-post-image">
                <div class="image_fx5">
                    <a href=<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $contributor->ID ); ?>><?php echo get_avatar( $contributor->user_email, '128' ); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!--author-image-->
                <div class="blog-post-title-box">
                    <div class="blog-post-title">
                    <h2>
                    <a href=<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $contributor->ID ); ?>><?php echo $contributor->display_name; ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--author-name-->
                    <div class="blog-post-content" style="padding-bottom: 0px; text-align: justify;">
                    <?php echo $contributor->description; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="author-info" style="margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px;">
                    <div id="author-desc" style="width: 100%;">
                    <ul class="author-social" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <?php if($contributor->facebook) { ?>
                    <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
                        <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo $contributor->facebook; ?>" class="fb-social-icon" target="_blank">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($contributor->twitter) { ?>
                    <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $contributor->twitter; ?>" class="twitter-social-icon" target="_blank">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($contributor->google) { ?>
                    <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
                        <a href="http://plus.google.com/<?php echo $contributor->google; ?>?rel=author" class="google-social-icon" target="_blank">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($contributor->pinterest) { ?>
                    <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
                        <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/<?php echo $contributor->pinterest; ?>?rel=author" class="pinterest-social-icon" target="_blank">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($contributor->instagram) { ?>
                    <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
                        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/<?php echo $contributor->instagram; ?>?rel=author" class="instagram-social-icon" target="_blank">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--author-desc-->
        </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
        <!--primary-->
    <div id="secondary">
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Category Sidebar')): endif; ?>
    </div>
    <!--secondary-->
</div>
<!--main-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_users()` uses a `WP_Query` object, which in turns passes your arguments to [`WP_User_Query::prepare_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/). If you refer to the previous linked documentation for this function, you'll see a parameter at the bottom called "has_published_posts".

> **'has_published_posts'**
>   (bool|array) Pass an array of post types to filter results to users who have published posts in those post types. `true` is an alias for all public post types.

Thus if you pass in `true` for this parameter, you will only get a list of users who have published posts for public `post_types`.

```php
// only return users with published posts
$args['has_published_posts'] = true;
// run the WP_Query
$contributors = get_users( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you so much @doublesharp. Exactly what I was looking for and definitely easier than I could imagine!